# Get last item from multiselection collection when keep holding pressed mouse left button

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, multi-select, selecteditem

I have a WPF MVVM apllication based on ListView. I have a little dilema which I described in following steps:

1. I multiselect several records with ctrl + mouse left button. Information of the last record always displays.
2. I press ctrl + a mouse left button on last record and keep holding mouse button. Information of first record displays.
3. I release mouse button and information of last record displays.

I have found information that "Since I have Multiple selection, the SelectedItem will always be the first selected in my selection."

Can I override behaviour and set Selecteditem to last element immediately? If yes, could you give me some advices how to achieve that? I will be greatful.

XAML:

```
 <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=EmployeeListView, Path=SelectedItems}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=EmployeeListView, Path=SelectedItems}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
```

Click Method:

```
public void ClickMethod(object parameter)
        {
            IList selection = (IList)parameter;

            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
        {
            if (SelectedEmployee == null)
            {
                IndexesOfSelectedEmployees.Clear();
                CountOfSelectedEmployees = 0;
                DynamicSearchEmployeeName = String.Empty;
                DynamicSearchEmployeeID = String.Empty;
                DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary = String.Empty;
                DynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner = String.Empty;
                DynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID = String.Empty;
            }

            if (SelectedEmployee != null)
            {
                foreach (Employee item in Employees)
                {
                    if (item.IsSelected == true)
                    {
                        IndexesOfSelectedEmployees.Add(Employees.IndexOf(item));
                    }
                    if (item.IsSelected == false)
                    {
                        IndexesOfSelectedEmployees.Remove(Employees.IndexOf(item));
                    }
                }

                SelectedEmployee = Employees[IndexesOfSelectedEmployees.Last()];

                foreach (int itemIndexesOfSelectedEmployees in IndexesOfSelectedEmployees)
                {
                    foreach (Employee itemEmployees in Employees)
                    {
                        if (itemIndexesOfSelectedEmployees == Employees.IndexOf(itemEmployees))
                        {
                            itemEmployees.IsSelected = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                CountOfSelectedEmployees = selection.Count;
            }
        }
        else if (!IndexesOfSelectedEmployees.Any())
        {
            IndexesOfSelectedEmployees.Clear();
            IndexesOfSelectedEmployees.Add(SelectedIndex.GetValueOrDefault());
            CountOfSelectedEmployees = selection.Count;
        }
        else if (IndexesOfSelectedEmployees.Any())
        {
            if (IndexesOfSelectedEmployees.Count == 1 && IndexesOfSelectedEmployees.Contains((int)SelectedIndex))
            {
                //IndexesOfSelectedEmployees.Add(Employees.IndexOf(SelectedEmployee));
                SelectedEmployee = null;
                CountOfSelectedEmployees = 0;
                IndexesOfSelectedEmployees.Clear();
                DynamicSearchEmployeeName = String.Empty;
                DynamicSearchEmployeeID = String.Empty;
                DynamicSearchEmployeeSalary = String.Empty;
                DynamicSearchEmployeeDesigner = String.Empty;
                DynamicSearchEmployeeEmailID = String.Empty;
            }
            else if (IndexesOfSelectedEmployees.Count == 1 && !IndexesOfSelectedEmployees.Contains((int)SelectedIndex))
            {
                IndexesOfSelectedEmployees.Clear();
                IndexesOfSelectedEmployees.Add(SelectedIndex.GetValueOrDefault());
                CountOfSelectedEmployees = 1; 
            }
            else if (IndexesOfSelectedEmployees.Count != 1)
            {
                IndexesOfSelectedEmployees.Clear();
                IndexesOfSelectedEmployees.Add(SelectedIndex.GetValueOrDefault());
                SelectedEmployee = Employees[IndexesOfSelectedEmployees.Last()];
                foreach (int itemIndexesOfSelectedEmployees in IndexesOfSelectedEmployees)
                {
                    foreach (Employee itemEmployees in Employees)
                    {
                        if (itemIndexesOfSelectedEmployees == Employees.IndexOf(itemEmployees))
                        {
                            itemEmployees.IsSelected = true;
                        }
                        if (itemIndexesOfSelectedEmployees != Employees.IndexOf(itemEmployees))
                        {
                            itemEmployees.IsSelected = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                CountOfSelectedEmployees = selection.Count;
            }
        }


    }
```

SelectionChanged Method:

```
    public void OnSelectionChanged(object parameter)
            {
                IList selection = (IList)parameter;

                if ((Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) && (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.A))) == true || (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) && Keyboard.I

sKeyDown(Key.Up)) || (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Down)))
            {
                CountOfSelectedEmployees = selection.Count;

                foreach (Employee item in selection)
                {
                    IndexesOfSelectedEmployees.Add(Employees.IndexOf(item));
                }                
                foreach (int itemIndexesOfSelectedEmployees in IndexesOfSelectedEmployees)
                {
                    foreach (Employee itemEmployees in Employees)
                    {
                        if (itemIndexesOfSelectedEmployees == Employees.IndexOf(itemEmployees))
                        {
                            itemEmployees.IsSelected = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try to handle the `SelectionChanged` event and access the `SelectedItems` property? It should contain all selected items.

Comment: Yes I did. And result is presented in a gif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. You have to revert a IndexesOfSelectedEmployees collection and it works.